# PsExec: batch file cannot create a file in remote server

Tags: asp.net, psexec

I'm facing on a crazy problem.

Using PsExec to run batch file remotely on server. When I use the same command argument in command line, all is fine.

Here is my batch file:

```
@ECHO OFF
ECHO %USER% >> "D:\Temp\TextFile.txt"
```

Here is my call to remote server:

```
var cmdFileOnRemoteServer = "D:\Temp\myBatchFile.cmd"
var cmdExe = @"C:\Exe\PsExec.exe";
var cmdArgs = string.Format(@"\\{0} -accepteula -u {1} -p {2} {3} {4}", serverName, userName, passWord, cmdFileOnRemoteServer, utilisateur;

 proc = new Process();
 proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
 proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
 proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
 proc.StartInfo.FileName = cmdExe;
 proc.StartInfo.Arguments = cmdArgs;
 proc.Start();
 proc.WaitForExit();
 var exitCode = proc.ExitCode;
```

exitCode = 0 in all time
I'm using Asp.NET MVC app using application pool.
I already use all option of PsExec.
I grand all privilege on remote server to application pool which run a website.
Website in installed in server which use PsExec.

All help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: try it without the Redirects for output and error. ECHO and >> are output redirectors, so you are likely running on a differant shell than you think you are when performing the echo. when you run psexec interactively it shares the invoker shell. just a hunch.

Comment: Hi Thomas, I always tried all scenario including yours, but the batch file cannot run.

Comment: have you permitted the user to login as a batch job? sometimes that is required. you can find the option in `secpol.msc` -> Local Policies -> security options

Comment: I've fixed some problem...and be able to see created file. But PsExec, need the opened session in same machine (which running PsExec), how the application pool can execute command file using PsExec without need that the same application pool opened a session

Comment: have you tried the -i switch to interact with the server session?

Comment: Thanks Thomas for your help, but I've use another solution without using PsExec tool which was WMI, and all is working fine.

Comment: wmi can be a great resource if it fits your needs. good luck.